# When you have variables in the entries of a matrix, what does it mean if a certain value of the variable gives an undefined result?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm given the matrix: \begin{bmatrix}-a-7&-2a-6 & 0\\a+3&a+3 &3a-3\\ -2a-14 & -4a-12 & a-1\end{bmatrix} and I wanted to determine which values of $a$ give the matrix only $1$ free variables, so I got the matrix into this echelon form: \begin{bmatrix}-a-7&-2a-6&0\\0&\left(\frac{(a+3)(1-a)}{a+7}\right)&3a-3 \\ 0 & 0 & a-1\end{bmatrix}

so clearly $a=1$ gives the matrix two free variables, so $3$ is not a solution,

and $a=-3$ gives the matrix a single free variable as desired, so $1$ is a solution.

Where I'm unclear is with $a=-7$ since that would make the top left entry $=0$, but it would also make the middle entry (second diagonal entry) be $(\frac{-32}{0})$ which is undefined since you  cannot divide by zero. But when I let $a=-7$ in the original matrix, I get $0$ free variables.

Am I missing something?

Comment: determinant $=(a+3)(a-1)^2$. you only need to check $a=1$ which gives nullity $= 2$, and $a=-3$ which gives nullity $= 1$

Comment: Oh snap! That's a really smart way of solving the problem! Because if the determinant is not equal to $0$, there are no free variables because it's invertible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we divide by a number, we check if it is zero and we can handle them separately. When $a=-7$.

The original matrix becomes

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 8 & 0 \\ -4 & -4 & -24 \\ 0 & 16 & -8\end{bmatrix}$$ which is clearly a ful rank matrix, hence your computation for $a=-7$ is right.

Note that when you mean $1$ free variable, if you mean the number of free parameter in a linear system which is the nullity. Then when $a=1$, the rank of your matrix is $1$ and hence the nullity is $2$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense! Thank you for clarifying! Also, I noticed my switch up with $a=1$ and $a=-3$ and the corresponding number of free variables. In this problem, the reason I'm looking for when the matrix only has one free variable is because I'm trying to find the values of $a$ for which the Null Space is spanned by a single vector (nullity of 1-dimension)! Thanks again for the help!